# 'What' followed by 'which'

Tags: pronouns, determiners

The present article is a brief report of observations and should not be taken as a comprehensive guideline for ***what*** conditions are deemed treatable by doctors and ***which*** are not.

Your thoughts on ***what*** and ***which*** in this sentence, please

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  I observe the author has what and which here. They have similar meanings. What do you what to ask about this?

Comment: This question may be too broad or may be considered off-topic as "proofreading". I am not sure what the question is exactly. Generally I would say that you could use either "what" or "which" here, but it seems awkward to use different words in the two positions.

Comment: I believe that 'what' might be changed to 'which' but 'which' at the end should not be changed to 'what'. At least to me it sounds very strange to replace 'which' with 'what'.

Comment: It's OK, though the writer could have been consistent with the interrogative pronouns "what" or "which". Syntactically, "what conditions are deemed treatable by doctors and which are not" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), where the meaning is "... should not be taken as a comprehensive guideline for the answer(s) to the questions 'What conditions are deemed treatable by doctors and which are not?'" Sam's answer below explains the contrast in meaning between "what" and "which".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compare these two phrases:

> 1. comprehensive guideline for what conditions are deemed treatable
> 2. comprehensive guideline for which conditions are deemed treatable

Both "what" and "which" may be used. The word "which" seems to suggest there are an exact, finite, known quantity of conditions and the guidelines are specifying them. These 10 out of 20. The word "what" is more general, there could be any number of conditions, and the guidelines are choosing some of them.

Next, these two phrases:

> 3. and which are not.
> 4. and what are not.

Here, only #3 is valid.  Certain conditions are being specifically excluded, and "which" is used when discussing more specific things.

Overall, there is a nearly unsolvable contradiction with the sentence as-is, and perhaps it should be more comprehensively rewritten.

- "which" should go with "which". "which are true and which are not." Therefore, use "which" in both cases.
- the first usage of "what" is preferable (some conditions out of a large unknown number).